# How can I find which song is currently playing programmatically?

Tags: command-line, bash, banshee

I'm trying to make a little bash script which I could call with a keyboard shortcut and which could detect which song is currently playing and vote it up or down, stuff like that.
How can I get information about the currently playing song? And what about the previous song?

I'm using Banshee, but maybe there is a way to get currently playing song which works with multiple players? Or maybe a general way which can be tweaked to work on different players?

Answer (score 4):

Oops, another question made me think of looking in the manual... Apparently it's really simple to get info about the currently playing song using the --query-* commands. From the manual:

```
   --query-uri
          URI

   --query-artist
          Artist Name

   --query-album
          Album Title

   --query-title
          Track Title
```